# How detailed data to store in Data Warehouse for loan processing?

Tags: database, data-warehouse, olap

I have to design data warehouse for loan application database,
and have problem with choosing how detailed data to store.
Application in OLTP db store capital and current balance processed once per month
but for reporting often is need to know current balance in any given date with calculated interest, fees etc. So the app generated this on the fly. The problem is - is this a good idea to store all those data for each day for each loan? That's going to be millions of records within a month! What is the best practice such situation? Still calculate part of the data?

Answer (score 0):

Tens, hundreds of millions of rows should not be an issue for OLAP softwares. For example, [icCube](http://www.icCube.com) is still processing in sub-second typical MDX requests for several hundreds of millions of facts. On the fly aggregations are fast and having details might be handy for detailed analysis of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer starting with the lowest grain available in the OLTP system. Data Processing times are not going to be very significant. The reason we use the lowest grain is that, when we need to add more attributes into our analysis we do not need to go back to the OLTP system and fetch the data. 
This grain is different from the grain of your data marts.

If you are using Kimball methodology, then you will have this grain in the ODS layer - Operational Data Store
If you are using Inmon methodology, then you will have this grain in the DWH layer - Data Warehouse